# Garage drain isn't draining, how can I figure out where it ends?

Tags: plumbing, drain, garage, floor, septic

My house is a 1977 ranch with double garage underneath and it has septic tanks. A round drain in the garage seems to go to the left as that's where the vacuum hose goes when I put it in the drain, but the septic is in back to the right.

How do I find out where the end is so I can see if it's flooding from all water coming down the hill? The house is set into the earth on the back cement wall. Maybe the drain is frozen? I've tried pouring hot water, and salt and vinegar into it.

Comment: Garage drain should not go into septic tank.  It should go to city storm drain or into gravel field down hill from your house.    If your garage is not subject to flooding, and the drain is only to catch snow melt from cars, it may not go anywhere, just a very small pocket of gravel under the floor and the water gets absorbed in the ground under the floor.  If it is subject to flooding it would help to know where your roof gutters, and other non-septic water goes.

Comment: You can get an inexpensive illuminated borescope from your favorite china supplier for under $10.00 depending on length. Simply poke that down the drain and see what you find. It may be a drain to nowhere or it may connect to the storm sewer. Food Luck

Comment: You could also check the original building plans for your home...